# Calculate the number of values ​in each field separately in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1 | w |
| B | 2 | e |
| A | 1 | p |

I want to get result like this:

| Column | CountByValue |
| --- | --- |
| B | 2 |
| A | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| w | 1 |
| e | 1 |
| p | 1 |

Is there any way to get the above result with SQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done like following also using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT V.[Column],COUNT(*) CountByValue
FROM MyTable T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT [Column]
    FROM (
        VALUES (T.ColumnA),(T.ColumnB),(T.ColumnC)) v([Column])
    ) v
GROUP BY V.[Column]
```

Comment: Thank You very mush. Wow. I haven't seen this Way, I try it!

Comment: You can remove the derived table `SELECT *` and query directly

Comment: @Charlieface, you are right... i have removed it as it was not required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `APPLY`, but you don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT V.[Column], COUNT(*)
FROM T CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (T.ColumnA), (T.ColumnB), (T.ColumnC)
     ) v(Column)
GROUP BY V.[Column]
```

Answer (score -1):

If values are distinct between columns you need `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT "Column A" AS "Column", COUNT() AS "CountByValue"
FROM "MyTable"
GROUP BY "Column A"

UNION ALL

SELECT "Column B", COUNT()
FROM "MyTable"
GROUP BY "Column B"

UNION ALL

SELECT "Column C", COUNT()
FROM "MyTable"
GROUP BY "Column C"
```

Comment: Thank You very mush. But if there are many fields to calculate, I will use a lot of "UNION ALL"? Will this performance not be good?
ps. The fields in the question are dynamic fields, there may be many or few